# pgfplots - Axis in bytes (KB, MB, GB, etc)

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I was wondering whether it is possible to have an axis ticks be marked in terms of bytes. I have the following plot:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\label{fig:buffer-example}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        ymode=log,
        axis lines=middle,
        x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
        y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={Size (Bytes)},
        xtick distance=32]
    % 60x^3+48x^2(x/2+1)+128x^2+4x^2(2x/10), x from 0 to 256
    \addplot [domain=0:256, smooth, thick] { x*x * (((424*x) / 5) + 176) };
    % 36x^3+48x^2(x/2+1)+128x^2+4x^2(2x/10)+(128x^2*4x^2(2x/10)*9), x from 0 to 256
    \addplot [domain=0:256, smooth, thick] { x*x * (176 + x * (304/5 + (4608*x*x)/5)) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{The memory footprint of the 2 Moving Plates configuration given $N=M=L=x$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: Output produced by the plot]

Instead of having the ticks on the y-axis be 10^2, 10^5, 10^8, etc I would like it to say 1KB, 1MB, 1GB, etc. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to this site You can see in the doc section 4.15 Tick Options p.342
`yticklabels={label list}`

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Comment: Voting to leave open. A closed question without an answer might get deleted by [roomba](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). To prevent this, it would be better if @pascal974 could convert their comment into a short answer to preserve this knowledge for future users with the same problem

Comment: @hpekristiansen Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8778/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Sure let us give it a few years.

Answer (score 3):

With `yticklabels={label list}`, in the doc section 4.15 Tick Options p.342.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!